# Resize embedded google map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, firebug

I tried asking question at super user first at https://superuser.com/questions/763734/how-to-get-larger-map-on-iss-live-stream, with no luck. I am just an observer watching the live Internation Space Station (ISS) stream whenever I get a chance. I don't own/can not modify at the source, the pages I am visiting. I just want to use firebug to enlarge element on the screen that's already there.

Site http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/ streams pictures from camera's on International Space Station. On right hand side there a flash window that shows trajectory and underneath it is a google map. On my monitor the current position with red dot is always lost as map size is very small and I don't get any options like centre here. Ctrl+ keys makes things little bigger, but problem essentially persists.

If I go to http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Where_is_the_International_Space_Station, I get same screen, but maps area is more usable, but I loose ability to watch live stream.

Is there any way I can set height of google maps using firebug or similar so that map is more usable and I can relate the actual location? I tried inspecting elements and changing various values, but could not figure out how height is managed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Setting/debugging css properties can be programming, even if its using firebug. That's why I asked the question. Agreed that its not my code, nor can I control it any way.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the maps origin element (most likely a `DIV`) and then run `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` in the JS console of your preferred browser (assumes that 'map' is a global var set to the map object - you have have to hunt for this).